# FineUploader onDelete and onComplete

Tags: php, jquery, fine-uploader

```
.on('complete', function(id, name, response) {
    console.log(id);
    console.log(response);
    console.log(name);
    $("input").attr({
        type: 'hidden',
        name: id
    }).val(name).appendTo('form');
})
.on('deleteComplete', function(id, xhr, isError) {
    console.log(name);
    $('input[name=' + id + ']').remove();
});
```

I'm using latest FineUploader to upload images and add the image filenames as hidden fields (correct way) to `post` their location to PHP for further processing.

The issue is `id` is common between the two callbacks but it returns an object and I'm sure how to handle it. I just need to store/post the filename location to PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters for your callbacks are incorrect.  If you are using the jQuery plug-in wrapper for Fine Uploader, each event handler always has an initial parameter of `Event`.  That is, the jQuery event object associated with the event you are handling.

Just to be clear, you code should look like this:

```
.on('complete', function(event, id, name, response) {
    ... 
})
.on('deleteComplete', function(event, id, xhr, isError) {
    ...
});
```

This is one of many reasons why I have advised users to avoid using the jQuery plug-in wrapper.  It makes working with Fine Uploader callbacks more confusing, and provides absolutely no benefits.  In light of this, if you still want to use the jQuery plug-in wrapper for some reason, you should consider declaring your callback handlers as part of a `callback` option passed as part of the initial configuration options when constructing a Fine Uploader instance.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Now I just need to figure how to delete the same hidden field inside `ondeleteComplete` that was created in `onComplete`

Comment: Why are you creating hidden fields and submitting a form again?  Fine Uploader sends the file names for each file in the upload POST request.

Comment: Oh? but I couldn't see anything with `echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST,1).'</pre>';`

Comment: I'm not sure what the code in your comment means.  Either way, the file name, among other details, is encoded in every upload POST request.  By default, every upload POST request is multipart encoded, so you'll need to ensure you are looking in the correct place in the request.

Comment: My  `app.php` contains a form and the same file also processes the submitted data. Image upload is a part of it but I can't retreive the file names so I'm looking to use hidden fields. I'm using the traditional server example to handle upload/deletion.